# How to observe Firebase changes in Flutter using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to observe Firebase collection changes. In the first run, Listview is not building. After changing data on Firebase, then listview is rendered properly but previous snapshot is used because I see my old data on the screen.

Any idea to find the error?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<VoteCubit, VoteState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == FormStatus.success) {
          print("Success");
        } else if (state.status == FormStatus.inprogress) {
          print("In progress");
        } else if (state.status == FormStatus.fail) {
          print("fail");
        } else {
          print("Empty Area");
        }
      },
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('liveSurvey').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final voteCubit = context.read<VoteCubit>();
          final voteState = voteCubit.state;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            voteCubit.getAllRooms(snapshot);
            print("Here");
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: voteState.rooms.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                print("Inside Listview");
                . . .
```

Comment: does this behqvior stqy the sq;e if you used StreamBuilder directly without BlocListener ?

Comment: I was exactly trying this right now, but yes. It is same

Comment: just use [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) - no need for `StreamBuilder` or `BlocListener`

Comment: I see that you're not using the snapshot.data inside the StreamBuilder, and you rely on the voteState.rooms list which is provided by bloc, I guess that relying on it instead of snapshot.data could get you to this behavior

Comment: @pskink but how to observe firebase changes if I don't use streambuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Use stream builder like this for real time data.

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("travellers/India/details")
            .where(
              'firestore_id',
              isEqualTo: widget.get_firestore_id,
            )
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    print('play lodader')
}else if (snapshot.hasData) {
print('your_ui_here')
}
```